# What are benefits of Soap over normal Xml?

Tags: .net, xml, soap

What are benefits of Soap?Why it is widely used in Web Services?

Comment: Pray tell, what is "normal XML" in the context of web services?

Comment: Soap is a mode of communication between Web Service and client.But say what makes it the mode of communication..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question could be equivalent to: What are the benefits of English over the English/Lating abecedary?

Soap is a standard to invoke remote methods with relatively low overhead (it comes from Simple Object Access Protocol), at least lower than other remote distributed logic systems such as plain old RPC, DCOM, Corba, etc. It uses XML as format, others used binary propietary formats, which has some advantages, such as reusing already existing XML-Processing code, and being easily transported over text-oriented-protocols such as HTTP.

The main benefit comes from being a widely used standard, which is there is a whole lot of support on many languages/platforms.

If you plan to use plain XML in a REST style service, you have to do it all yourself (data conversions, object instantiation and invokation, etc.). With SOAP you can concentrate on just writing the logic.